# how to get one component from another module angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

In angular 2 how to import specific component from other module

In home.module.ts `appComponent` i need exports and import to other module tranfer.module.ts 
After import homeModule when click tranfer page shows home page
  how to get specific component?

```
 import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule }  from '@angular/common';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { NgaModule } from '../../theme/nga.module';

    import { routing }       from './home.routing';
    import { homeComponent } from './home.component';
    import { recharge } from './recharge';
    import { mobile } from './mobile/mobile.component';
    import { appComponent } from './appComponent/appComponent.component';
    import { appService } from './appComponent/appComponent.service';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        NgaModule,
        routing
      ],
      declarations: [
        recharge,
        mobile,
        appComponent,
        homeComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        appService
      ],
      exports: [
            appComponent
      ]
    })
    export default class homeModule {}
```

tranfer.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }  from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgaModule } from '../../theme/nga.module';

import { routing }       from './tranfer.routing';
import  homeModule from '../home/home.module';
import { tranfer } from './tranfer.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgaModule,
    homeModule,
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [
    tranfer
  ]
})
```

home.routes.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule }  from '@angular/router';
import { homeComponent } from './home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: homeComponent
  }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

Comment: whats the error you are getting ?

Comment: not get any error when click tranfer page shows home page

Comment: Where's your routing declaration?

Comment: https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin  using this template